# Why would SwingUtilities.invokeLater be throwing a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I'm getting an exception being thrown intermittently, about one in every five executions of my application, when I try to pass a runnable to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.  It seems to only happen when the application starts up, maybe before the Event Dispatch Thread is properly setup?  I'm not really sure, but if the application comes up properly, then I don't have any problems after that.  Here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
    at com.mypackage.MyClass.myMethod(MyClass.java:126)
```

I'm not sure why a call to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` would die like this.  There must be something goofy going on.  For reference, here is the actual source code of `MyClass.java`:

```
118:    public void myMethod(final VariableA variableA, final VariableB variableB, final VariableC variableC) {
119:        if (variableA == null)
120:            throw new NullPointerException("no variable A");
121:        if (variableB == null)
122:            throw new NullPointerException("no variable B");
123:        if (variableC == null)
124:            throw new NullPointerException("no variable C");
125:
126:        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
127:            @Override
128:            public void run() {
129:                MyClass.this.processMyMethod(variableA, variableB, variableC);
130:            });
131:        }
132:    }
```

Any ideas here what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you calling this method from the constructor? In that case the MyClass.this can be null probably.

Comment: Not sure if this'll help, but can you post `processMyMethod()` also?

Comment: @GáborBakos that is a very good point.

Comment: @GáborBakos The stack trace would look very different if that were even possible.

Comment: Please post the whole stack trace as well; how you get there might be important.

Comment: Examining the source to `EventQueue.invokeLater()` (JDK 1.6, YMMV), it doesn't look like there's much that could be `null` apart from the `EventQueue` itself. To debug this you could try checking whether `Toolkit.getEventQueue()` is null. I've never seen it before, though. Can you move this code to something that will be triggered by a Swing event itself, e.g. on displaying your main window?

Comment: `processMyMethod()` sets up `JXTreeTable` nodes based on the data received.  It's fairly long, and it's a private member of `MyClass`.  Also, `MyClass` extends `DefaultTreeTableModel`.

Comment: At the moment, the error has stopped happening.  So I'm wondering if it has to do with some intermittent network condition, or something that's delaying execution of certain components.  When it happens again, I will return and add the details you have requested to my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is one case that would fit, though a bit contrary to the observation "at the beginning" - involving *serialisation*.

Whether this still is the case can be seen fast:

```
class A {
    class B implements Serializable {
    }
}
```

Now after being reloaded a B object might have an `A.this` being null.

This might concern MyClass.this (unlikely), or one of the final variables. In which case the correct solution would be to make class  B `static`.

But that all is speculation on speculation. One dubious speculation is that `processMyMethod` uses base classes as parameters, and their this being null. And somehow already getting an exception earlier (?). So MyClass.this null?

Comment: As I already commented, the stuff in `run` is irrelevant because the stack trace shows the exception is thrown on the thread making the call to `invokeLater`.